# Jimi(java): Noclassdeffound exception upon Jimi.createJimiWriter

Tags: java, applet, package, noclassdeffounderror

I hesitated to ask this, but i have spent numerous hours messing with environmental variables, I just cannot figure this out:

I am trying to save whatever is displayed on an applet into an image file, after some research i thought JIMI was my best bet
(below is not my original work, but a simple example from http://www.coderanch.com/t/337338/GUI/java/save-applet-image-gif-jpeg as to what i will be doing)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.sun.jimi.core.Jimi;
import com.sun.jimi.core.JimiWriter;

public class JimiApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    private ImageCanvas canvas;
    private TextField filename;
    private Button save, clear;

    public void init() {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        canvas = new ImageCanvas();
        add( canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        Panel p = new Panel();
        filename = new TextField();
        save = new Button( "Save" );
        save.addActionListener( this );
        clear = new Button( "Clear" );
        clear.addActionListener( this );
        p.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = .70;
        p.add( filename, c );
        c.weightx = .15;
        p.add( save, c );
        c.weightx = .15;
        p.add( clear, c );
        add( p, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        if ( e.getSource() == save ) {
            save.setEnabled( false );
            filename.setEnabled( false );
            filename.setEditable( false );
            Thread t = new Thread( new SaveButtonPressed() );
            t.start();
        } else if ( e.getSource() == clear ) {
            canvas.clear();
        }
    }

    private static class ImageCanvas extends Canvas implements MouseMotionListener {
        private Vector points;

        public ImageCanvas() {
            points = new Vector();
            addMouseMotionListener( this );
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            points.add( p );
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void clear() {
            points.removeAllElements();
            repaint();
        }

        public void paint( Graphics g ) {
            int size = points.size();
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            if ( size > 0 ) {
                Point p1 = (Point)points.get( 0 );
                for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                    Point p2 = (Point)points.get( i );
                    g.drawLine( p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y );
                    p1 = p2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class SaveButtonPressed implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Thread t = new Thread( new SaveRunnable() );
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch( InterruptedException x ) { 
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                save.setEnabled( true );
                filename.setEnabled( true );
                filename.setEditable( true );
            }
        }

    }

    private class SaveRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            int width = canvas.getSize().width;
            int height = canvas.getSize().height;
            ColorModel cm = canvas.getColorModel();
            int[] pixels = new int[ width * height ];
            Image image = canvas.createImage( width, height );
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            canvas.paint( g );
            PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber( image, 0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width );
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                success = pg.grabPixels();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            if ( success ) {
                String mimeType = "invalid";
                String extension = filename.getText();
                int index = extension.indexOf( '.' );
                extension = extension.substring( index +1);
                System.out.println(extension);
                if ( extension.equalsIgnoreCase( "GIF" ) ) {
                    mimeType = "/image/gif";
                } else if ( extension.equalsIgnoreCase( "JPG" )  ||
                        extension.equalsIgnoreCase( "JPEG" ) ) {
                    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                } else if ( extension.equalsIgnoreCase( "PNG" ) ) {
                    mimeType = "image/png";
                }

                // You can add more options here for the different image types 
                // you want to support.

                if ( mimeType.equals( "invalid" ) ) {
                    System.err.println( "Could not get a valid mime type from file extension!" );
                    return;
                } else {
                    try {
                        OutputStream imageOutput = null;

                        // Do something here to get an OutputStream pointing to the socket, 
                        // URL of servlet, etc. that you are going to write your image to.
                        System.out.println("got here " + mimeType);
                        JimiWriter writer = Jimi.createJimiWriter( mimeType );
                        System.out.println("probably not here");
                        writer.setSource( image );
                        writer.putImage( imageOutput );
                    } catch ( Exception x ) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println( "PixelGrabber failed!" );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I can compile this code with JIMI in my environmental variables. However, upon trying to save the image I get the error:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jimi/core/Jimi
           at JimiApplet$SaveRunnable.run(JimiApplet.java:165)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jimi.core.Jimi
            at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:211)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
            at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:144)
            at java.land.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
            ... 2 more
```

After research i found that this is mostly likly caused by not having jimiproclasses in my environmental variables, so i tried to add them doing numerous combinations, took me an hour an a half to do all combinations i thought would work
In CLASSPATH AND in PATH, here are a few things i tried:

```
    C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi;
    C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi\JimiProClasses.zip;
    C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi;C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi\JimiProClasses.zip;
    C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi\src\classes
```

I have tried more combinations, but i believe you can get the gist here
With each of the examples above, i can compile (which shows that some form of Jimi is working) i just simply cannot do Jimi.createJimiWriter without receiving error in runtime

Anybody's help is greatly appreciated. I am sorry if this seems a nooby question, but I have worked on it so long and i attacked it so meticulously i felt i had no place left to turn!

Comment: *"trying to save whatever is displayed on an applet into an image file, after some research i thought JIMI was my best bet"*  I didn't bother to research JIMI, but a sand-boxed applet can get a view by calling `paint/paintConponent(Graphics)` on the main component then saving it using a JNLP API `FileContents` object.  A trusted applet could use the `Robot`/`File`.  So why is JIMI needed?

Answer (score 0):

Applets don't get their classpath from the CLASSPATH enviroment variable.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497808/jar-applet-classpath) for info about how to set the classpath for an applet.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work, which i imagine reflects more on my than the answer. Tried codebase="C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi\JimiProClasses.zip" archive = "C:\Users\dfreelan\Dropbox\colormap\Jimi\JimiProClasses.zip", and a few different things to no avail. I know I am going to need to do this one day for real, and I will definitely be looking back at this answer when the time comes. Thank you again!